# Why does this code output undefined and then raise a TypeError?

Tags: javascript

```js
function foo() {
  if (true) {
    function bar() { 
      console.log("bar");
    }
  } else {
    function qux() { 
      console.log("qux"); 
    }
  }
  
  console.log(qux); 
  qux(); 
}

foo();
```

```markdown
undefined
TypeError: qux is not a function
```

I don't understand the output of this code. Why does `console.log(qux)` log `undefined`? Why do I not get `Uncaught ReferenceError: qux is not defined` on the `console.log` instead?

When functions declarations are hoisted, are they not defined or are they initialized to a value of `undefined`?

Comment: Because you did not define `qux`!

Comment: You never reach the `function qux()` path, so the name `qux`'s value is `undefined`.

Comment: Consider defining both of the functions before the if, and then running either function inside the if instead?

Comment: Some basic debugging would have determined that `if (true)` would never reach the else branch and therefore `qux` is never defined.

Comment: Ironically this question got down voted, but it's actually a good question, but it could have maybe had a bit more detail on what you was expecting.  eg.  Why do I not get `Uncaught ReferenceError: qux is not defined` on the `console.log`.  This would have made things more clear.. :)

Comment: Another way to look at this `function x() {}` has the same scope as `var x = 1`,  and if you `console.log(x)` before it's assigned you would get `undefined`.  IOW: function & var scope the same way.  So in modern JS, what you normally now do is -> `const x = 1`  or `let x = 1`, and this will make them `block` scoped, you can do the same for functions `const x = () => {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `qux` is never defined as the if statement never reaches the `else` condition.

Modifying your code to the following will solve the problem. There is no need to conditionally (use an if statement) to define a function.

```
function foo() {
  function bar() { 
    console.log("bar");
  }
  function qux() { 
    console.log("qux"); 
  }
  
  console.log(qux); 
  qux(); 
}

foo();
```

**UPDATE:**

The error is a `TypeError` because the function declaration is hoisted to the top of the parent function scope. If the function is never declared, then you will get a `ReferenceError` message.

Comment: If `qux` is never defined why doesn't the code throw an error instead of logging `undefined`?

Comment: I get the error "undefined" when running the code

Comment: Oh, so the question is rather, why doesn't the console.log line already throw a ReferenceError instead?

Comment: @Chibi  functions are hoisted to top of (function scope), but are defined in order of execution.  If you defined your function using `const`, you can make them `block` scoped instead.